# Get logined user in AuthServiceProvider Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to access a logined user model and its relations in `AuthServiceProvider` in Laravel 5.4

But I know I can't access `Auth::user()` because its defined after this service

Is there a way to access the user model somehow?

Comment: I'd suggest to specify why you need to access the user model. This way, it will be easier for others to suggest workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

In `AuthServiceProvider`'s `boot()` function write these lines of code

```
view()->composer('*', function($view){
  $view->with('currentUser', Auth::user());
});
```

Here `*` means - in all of your composers `$currentUser` variable is available.

Then, from view file `{{ currentUser }}` will give you the Authenticated User info.